# In the IBM Dynamic Workload Console, the Plan View freezes with Internet Explorer 7 in Jazz for Service Management v1.1.2 on Workload Scheduler

Tags: dynamic, console, workload-scheduler

using Internet Explorer 7, my window freezes for about 5 minutes when I perform some actions in sequence. After this, the browser window resumes. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Dynamic Workload Console website to the Local intranet security zone of Internet Explorer 7, with its default security level.